# Excel task: comparing columns

Tags: excel

Column A contains thousands of strings which are to an irregular amount identical. My goal is to add a formula (Col B) which gives me the following result in Col B:

```
Col A       Col B
GX01065227  1
GX01065227  1
GX01065227  1
GX01065227  1
GX00182922  2
GX00182922  2
GX00100933  3
GX00100933  3
GX00100933  3
GX00100933  3
GX00100933  3
```

In words, the column B should result in a 1 if the value is the same as the value above but if another value occurs it should be 2 and with the next different value 3 and with the next different value 4 etc.

Is there any idea how to get this result?

Comment: You want a vba solution or an Excel formula solution?

Comment: What Serge showed up is perfect! Thank you Lowpar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your list begins in the top-left corner (ie A1), follow these steps:

1. In B2, hard-code `1` as the cell value.
2. In B3, write `=IF(A2=A3,B2,B2+1)`.
3. Copy the formula from B3 down, as necessary.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Hi Serge, that's exactly what a was looking for! Thank you very much!